# c:\windows\system32\config\SYSTEM file corrupted in Windows XP EMBEDDED

Tags: boot, windows-xp-embedded

I have this problem with windows xp embedded...
Normally (using XP) I'd just copy the file from the repair folder (c:\windows\repair) but in this case I get no repair folder...

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is a big old chunk of your registry and is not something that can easily be replaced by another file.

The first thing I would try doing is to perform a system restore.  You can do the system restore from *outside* Windows using the Recovery Console provided by your Windows XP Embedded installation CD.

Once you are at the recovery console, follow the Microsoft KB article titled [**How to recover from a corrupted registry that prevents Windows XP from starting**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545) and away you go.  It shows you how to get to the recovery console from the CD if you are unsure.

If it's successful, you should suffer minimal (if any) data loss and be up and running as though nothing happened.  If it's not successful... hmm, yeah, I would mount the disk in another computer and recover whatever data you need and then reinstall Windows from scratch.

Comment: Definitely not working my friend... :(
When I start windows xp embedded install I get into a strange desktop (wallpaper with a mountain and a moon) and a ms dos window...
Inside windows xp embedded cd no trace of the "system" file I need...

Answer (score 1):

Use "Disable automatic restart after system failure" when booting by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>. It works!